# Questions regarding obviously pirated movies

Tags: discussion, policy

So we have this question regarding The Expendables 3 show up this morning.

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23462/the-expendables-3-rustys-bar-song

The problem? [The Expendables 3 hasn't been released yet.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Expendables_3) As shown in the linked Wikipedia entry for the movie, it has its premiere on 4 August 2014 in London, so this coming Monday. Further, it's not released to American theaters until 15 August 2014, so a little more than 3 weeks from now.

A quick Google search shows that a high quality copy of the movie has [already leaked to torrent sites](http://www.indiewire.com/article/expendables-3-leaked-online-what-does-it-mean-for-indie-filmmakers-20140725).

As such, do we have a policy regarding questions asked involving obviously pirated content, and if not, should we?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think that this is of our concern so much at all. While assuming piracy might be a reasonable deduction, we just don't know. And even more than that, it seems irrelevant. **As long as the question does not propagate or encourage piracy or link to pirated content, it seems not relevant where and how the OP has watched the movie.** And in the end, he might as well have watched it in a preview screening as a journalist, or even a sneak preview accessible to any public movie goer. I'd thus question the *"obviously pirated"* in the first place, which robs the whole problem of its premise, I think.

Likewise might there very well be questions about already released movies asked by people who also watched a pirated copy, but we don't worry about those either, since neither can we prove anything nor does it matter for the site or the question. Likewise we wouldn't talk about this matter had the question been asked some days later, which makes the whole problem somehow *"too localized"* anyway.

**This is just not our business to worry about.**

Comment: I agree - its not our business to enforce how other people watch the movie.

Comment: It wasn't so much about us enforcing how others watch a movie, and more so running the risk of drawing the ire of parties trying to prevent this sort of thing from happening by answering questions for a movie that hasn't been legally released yet. I don't agree with piracy personally, but I also don't care what someone else does of their own volition. Overall I agree in that, so long as they aren't actively encouraging piracy or link to sites enabling piracy, it's likely not that bad. I'll leave this open for a few more days in the event someone has a different argument.