# Can I ask a question about the unaired, leaked episodes of Game of Thrones?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

[The first four episodes of Game of Thrones Season 5 have been leaked.](http://techcrunch.com/2015/04/12/game-of-thrones-season-5-episode-leak/) Is it allowed to ask questions about the unaired, leaked episodes here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the answer to [this highly related question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1381/49):

I don't think that it is of our concern in which way you watched a movie or TV-show. While assuming piracy might be a reasonable deduction, we just don't know. And even more than that, it seems irrelevant. **As long as the question does not propagate or encourage piracy or link to pirated content, it seems not relevant where and how you watched a movie or TV-shows.** And in the end, you might as well have watched it in a preview screening as a journalist or something similar.

Likewise might there very well be questions about already released movies asked by people who also watched a pirated copy, but we don't worry about those either, since neither can we prove anything nor does it matter for the site or the question. Likewise we wouldn't talk about this matter if you asked your question a few weeks later, which makes the whole problem somehow *"too localized"* anyway.

**This is just not our business to worry about.**

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't put spoilers in the question subject and maybe note that the question is about un-aired episodes, I don't see an issue.

See the spoiler section on the [Help page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: No point in overuse of spoiler markup, it doesn't hide the text of the question in feeds so people are still going to see it and it's just annoying to remove at a later date.

Comment: @Flyk Oh, does it not? That's disappointing. Yet another reason to **not** use that page.  Oh well. I'll remove then.